# Find unique string size

Tags: arrays, string, algorithm, dynamic-programming

Given two strings `A` and `B` of equal lengths `n`.
For every index `0<=i<n` I can swap characters of A and B.

We need to minimize the number of unique characters in each of A and B.

if  `num(A)` = unique characters in string A

and `num(B)` = unique characters in string B

after all the operations.

print `max(num(A), num(B))`.

eg:

1).  `input:`  A= ababa B= babab `output:` 1

2).  `input:`  A= abaaa B= baabb `output:` 2

3).  `input:`  A= abcdefb B= bfedcba `output:` 4

In 3).  case, initially max(n(abcdefb),n(bfedcba)) = 6. You can modify the two strings such that they are "bbcdcbb" and "afedefa". String A has 3 unique characters and String B has 4 unique characters. Hence answer is 4. You cannot do better.

Comment: How do you define unique character? For example in `afedefa` only the `d` is unique, all others appear twice.

Comment: @Henry: in `afedefa` there are 4 unique characters a,f,e and d.

Comment: What's the size of the alphabet? What's the size of the strings?

Comment: @amit: alphabet size is lowercase a-z. And max string length is 100.